# Decode JSON from server in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a JSON file that needs decoding as it has {"Text" and then the actual message I send, inside my DB it stores under "content". I am trying to decode it to have clean data inside my table.

I have tried to make my controller decode it but it doesn't seem to do anything nor give me an error. I have attached a photo so you can see what I mean. I am not getting any errors with my controller but it just doesn't seem to have any effect either. I need to define the variable content inside my controller but if I change from return view details, message => $message to details, content => content I get non-object errors (Since decode it is now an array).

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use App\Suggestion;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials;
use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Propaganistas\LaravelPhone\PhoneNumber;

class DetailsController extends BaseController
{
    public function index($id)
    {

        $message = Message::find($id);
        $content = json_decode($message->content,TRUE);

        return view('details', ['message' => $message]);

    }
}
```

`

My Blade file is just a table which most important part is:

```
<td>{{$message->type}}</td>
<td>{{$message->content}}</td>
<td>{{$message->response}}</td>
<td>{{$message->id}}</td>
```

Once I can convert this into an array I can explode it into more respectable columns, I have attached an image of the UI so you can see what I'm trying to do

[UI image showing where content is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F66JG.png)

Comment: what is working / what is not working / what are you attempting to get working?

Comment: i'll tidy my question, I want to decode the JSON file so it shows the data inside the table separated instead of with all the { and [

Comment: Are you having problem with this line `$body = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);`? The `$response->getBody()` part seems wrong, from where is this data coming from? You have a `return` on the line before this, so this code won't be executed.

Comment: I think that is where the issue is, the data comes from a Google API which creates the JSON and stores it inside the MYSQL DB which I'm hosting through XAMPP, the table is Messages and has a field named content which is where the values are coming from

Comment: What I need to do is pull them from the DB as they are for example: "{"text":"message","suggestions":[{"reply":{"text":"test"}", decode it to be message, test

Comment: What I am saying is that this `$response` variable is not declared anywhere, nor provided as a parameter. Also, you have the `return` statement in the middle of the function.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right I moved the return statement to the bottom and it shows an error under the response variable, I will try this: 

$response = $client->request(
                'POST',
                "+{$message->messageId}".'/agentMessages',
                [
                    'body' => json_encode(
                        [
                            'contentMessage' => json_decode($message->content)

                        ]
                    ),
                ]
            );

Comment: `$response = $client->request(
                'POST',
                "+{$message->messageId}".'/agentMessages',
                [
                    'body' => json_encode(
                        [
                            'contentMessage' => json_decode($message->content)

                        ]
                    ),
                ]
            );`

Comment: Okay so I delcared the variables and added a `$response = $client->request(
            'POST',
            "+{$message->msisdn}".'/agentMessages',
            [
                'body' => json_encode(
                    [
                        'contentMessage' => json_decode($message->content)

                    ]
                ),
            ]
        );` 

$client links to the JSON, I now have to add the 'body' => json_encode(
 [ 
my variables will go HERE
]

I no longer get any dependency errors but it doesn't seem to be changing it at all

Comment: @GusCosta I have updated it but still haven't fixed it, I updated the post to show what I've got, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at the image you attached, it seems you want to display the raw JSON on the column. If that's the case, you don't need to decode it. Keep `content` as it is and pass `$mesage` to the view.

Check my code below:

```php
    public function index($id)
    {
        $message = Message::find($id);
        return view('details', ['message' => $message]);
    }
```

No need to change the template.

```
<td>{{$message->type}}</td>
<td>{{$message->content}}</td>
<td>{{$message->response}}</td>
<td>{{$message->id}}</td>
```

Comment: Great minds think alike, this is the same as what I came to. The issue is I am trying to pull it from Google not the DB I changed it so that I am instead using the DB by 

`$message = Message::find($id);
        $content = json_decode($message->content,TRUE);
        print_r($content);

        return view('details', ['message' => $message]);
    }
}`

Comment: In this case, it shouldn't be `return view('details', ['content' => $content]); } }`?

Comment: No it still loads with `return view('details', ['message' => $message]);` But the changes aren't implemented when running `return view('details', ['content' => $content]);` it gives an undefined variable error, do you know if any changes need to be made to the blade to make it work? If so what? 

`

Comment: returning the view `return view('details', ['content' => $content]);` is an unreachable statement problem

Comment: The variable name on the template should match the name you defined on `view()`. In this case `<td>{{$content->type}}</td>`.

Comment: I see what you're saying I tried that but I still need to return the view with `return view('details', ['message' => $message]);` else will get errors, is it possible to return both at the same time? Or do I need to change all the tables from `<td>{{$message->type}}</td>` to `<td>{{$content->type}}</td>` surely that doesn't sound correct? :/

Comment: If we change them all to $content from $message we get a non-object error

Comment: If I do `var_dump($content)` we get `array(2) { ["text"]=> string(4) "test" ["suggestions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["reply"]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(4) "test" ["postbackData"]=> string(36) "e05ad1f0-a0f8-4a56-a8c7-67f56ba9fe4c" } } } }
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213662/discussion-between-asp-net-mvc-student-programmer-and-gus-costa).

Comment: I private messaged you because I think we need to explode it and it will give the result, we definitely did need to decode it first though